# Distribute an operation on the cartesian product of two sets

Tags: core-language

I've been trying some different approach but all are not working:

I've got 2 polls, the first with 2 options (and 2 list of people which voted each option), the second with 3 options (and 3 list of people).
pollA = {pMenoDi25Anni, pPiùDi25Anni};
pollB = {pLavoroFullTime, pStudioEBasta, pLavoroPartTime};

I'd like to calculate the intersection between each element of pollB (each of which is a set) and pMenoDi25Anni.

I've tried using Thread

```
In: Thread[Intersection[
  pMenoDi25Anni, {pLavoroFullTime, pLavoroPartTime, pStudioEBasta}] ]
Out: {pMenoDi25Anni \[Intersection] pLavoroFullTime, 
 pMenoDi25Anni \[Intersection] pLavoroPartTime, 
 pMenoDi25Anni \[Intersection] pStudioEBasta}
```

[image]

It looks like exactly what I am looking for , but after assigning the real values to the this variables I get an unexpected result
pLavoroFullTime = {1, 2};
pLavoroPartTime = {3, 4};
pStudioEBasta = {5, 6};
pMenoDi25Anni = {1, 3, 5};

In: Thread[Intersection[
pMenoDi25Anni, {pLavoroFullTime, pLavoroPartTime, pStudioEBasta}] ]
Out: {}

Can you explain me what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MMA arguments are evaluated before feeding them to a function. This means

```
Intersection[pMenoDi25Anni, {pLavoroFullTime, pLavoroPartTime, 
  pStudioEBasta}]
```

is evaluated before feeding to Thread. Now, Intersection takes lists as arguments. This is fine for the first argument, but the second argument is a list of lists. Therefore, the intersection is empty.

What you want is "Map", for short "/@":

```
Clear[pLavoroFullTime, pLavoroPartTime, pStudioEBasta, pMenoDi25Anni];
pLavoroFullTime = {1, 2}; pLavoroPartTime = {3, 
  4}; pStudioEBasta = {5, 6}; pMenoDi25Anni = {1, 3, 5};
Intersection[pMenoDi25Anni, #] & /@ {pLavoroFullTime, pLavoroPartTime,
   pStudioEBasta}

(*{{1}, {3}, {5}}*)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. To better understand the Wolfram Language, is there any method to generalize this intersection to any List of Lists using Tuples or Outer? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257645/outer-vs-tuples-whats-the-meaning-of-this-sentence-from-the-wolfram-ref @Daniel Huber

Comment: I mean Intersection[{pMenoDi25Anni, pMoreThan25YearsOld}, {pLavoroFullTime, pLavoroPartTime, 
  pStudioEBasta}] the 1st element of the 1st list intersect 1st element of second list, then with the second, then with the 3rd and so on

Comment: Look at "MapThread"

Comment: thanks a lot!!!