# Outer vs Tuples, what's the meaning of this sentence from the Wolfram ref?

Tags: core-language

Results from Outer involve extra sublists:

```
In[1]:= Outer[List, {a, b}, {x, y, z}]

Out[1]= {{{a, x}, {a, y}, {a, z}}, {{b, x}, {b, y}, {b, z}}}

In[2]:= Tuples[{{a, b}, {x, y, z}}]

Out[2]= {{a, x}, {a, y}, {a, z}, {b, x}, {b, y}, {b, z}}
```

(it's from ref/Tuples , Properties&Relations)

Comment: It's just showing that Outer introduces extra lists compared to Tuples. Easier to see with `Outer[F, {a, b}, {x, y, z}]` vs `Tuples[F[{a, b}, {x, y, z}]]` where the `List` head has been replaced with `F`. Here you can think of Outer as producing a 2D grid of pairings of your elements, while Tuples is just listing those pairs .

Comment: `Tuples` returns a 6x2 nested list.  `Outer` returns a 2x3x2 nested list.  The documentation describes this as extra sublists.